# WPF won't allow more than 1 RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to create a chat application and Im trying to utilize the RichTextBox control for the chat log, the textbox for the user to enter the message and the users online board. But WPF wont allow me to have more than 1 RichTextBox. Whenever I copy paste the only richtextbox on the window WPF creates a copy of it but deletes the first RTB . It also wont allow me to drag and drop one. What do I have to tweak to allow myself to drop more controls ?

Comment: A bit of your xaml code would be useful here I think

Comment: more likely it is Visual Studio Designer problem. if you are trying to add (drag&drop) RichTextBox into some ContentControl, not into Panel, designer replaces previous content (previous RTB)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aLY5ia0A  , the code!

Answer (score 0):

You can place a `Grid` or any other `Panel` like `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, etc. in the Window and put 2 RichTextBoxes in it. `Window` is a `ContentControl` which means it can hold only 1 control. Grid is a `Panel` so it can hold as many controls as you want.

You can make Columns and rows in the Grid or use Margin explicitly to position your `RichTextBox`es.

Answer (score 0):

Any `Window` can only have one child element. In your case, depending on how you intend to layout your RTBs, you would need some sort of `Panel`. Here's a good [place to start](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/).

Here's a really quick example (stripped down) explaining a bit more:

```
<Window>
    <!-- You could put a RTB here, but that would become your root control, and it can't have any siblings -->
    <Grid>

        <!-- Use something like this to layout your inner RichTextBoxes -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" /> // using 9/10 of the available vertical space
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" /> // using 1/10 of the available vertical space
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Here you can put multiple controls -->
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0"></RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1"></RichTextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```